# Creating a single tidy seaborn plot in a 'for' loop

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm trying to generate a plot in seaborn using a *for* loop to plot the contents of each dataframe column on its own row.

The number of columns that need plotting can vary between 1 and 30.  However, the loop creates multiple individual plots, each with their own x-axis, which are not aligned and with a lot of wasted space between the plots.  I'd like to have all the plots together with a shared x-axis without any vertical spacing between each plot that I can then save as a single image.

The code I have been using so far is below.

`comp_relflux = measurements.filter(like='rel_flux_C', axis=1)` *# Extracts relevant columns from larger dataframe
`comp_relflux=comp_relflux.reindex(comp_relflux.mean().sort_values().index, axis=1)` *# Sorts into order based on column mean.*

```
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [12.00, 1.00]
for column in comp_relflux.columns:
    plt.figure()
    sns.scatterplot((bjd)%1, comp_relflux[column], color='b', marker='.')
```

[This is a screenshot of the resultant plots.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxzLk.png)

I have also tried using FacetGrid, but this just seems to plot the last column's data.

```
p = sns.FacetGrid(comp_relflux, height=2, aspect=6, despine=False)
p.map(sns.scatterplot, x=(bjd)%1, y=comp_relflux[column])
```

Comment: Use .melt on the dataframe, and then sns.relplot

Comment: This question is not reproducible without **data**. This question needs a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Please see [How to provide a reproducible dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52413246/7758804), then **[edit] your question**, and paste the clipboard into a code block. Always provide a [mre] **with code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, plot images are okay. If you don't include an mre, it is likely the question will be downvoted, closed, and deleted.

Answer (score 1):

To combine the x-axis labels and have just one instead of having it for each row, you can use `sharex`. Also, using `plt.subplot()` to the number of columns you have, you would also be able to have just one figure with all the subplots within it. As there is no data available, I used random numbers below to demonstrate the same. There are 4 columns of data in my df, but have kept as much of your code and naming convention as is. Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
comp_relflux = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 4)) #Random  data - 4 columns
bjd=np.linspace(0,1,100) # Series of 100 points - 0 to 1
rows=len(comp_relflux.columns) # Use this to get column length = subplot length
fig, ax = plt.subplots(rows, 1, sharex=True, figsize=(12,6)) # The subplots... sharex is assigned here and I move the size in here from your rcParam as well

for i, column in enumerate(comp_relflux.columns):
    sns.scatterplot((bjd)%1, comp_relflux[column], color='b',marker='.', ax=ax[i])
```

**1 output plot with 4 subplots**

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly, exactly what I was looking to achieve, thanks.